# How to hide inline annotations when using the VS Code Diagnostics API

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm currently working with the VS Code Diagnostics API and so far it works really well but I want to hide the inline annotation in the code – how can this be achieved?

I speak about the yellow / orange text which starts with `[translation:....`

[image: inline annotation of extension]

I want to keep the yellow underlines & the appearance in the "Diagnostic" tab but only hide the inline text display.

Can this be achieved? I did not find anything on the VS Code Extension docs.
Thank you!!

Comment: There are various properties associated with a `vscode.Diagnostic`.  I'm guessing it's `source` or `tags` maybe?  Can you show the code you're using to create the diagnostic?